# How check if ACCESS_RESTRICTED_SETTINGS is enabled?

Tags: android, android-13, android-tiramisu

Is there some Java code to check if the [`ACCESS_RESTRICTED_SETTINGS`](https://support.google.com/android/answer/12623953?hl=en) permission is enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean hasAccessRestrictedPerm(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow("android:access_restricted_settings", applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
        return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error when i used this code: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: verifyIncomingOp: uid 11488 does not have android.permission.MANAGE_APPOPS. 

And also i tried to add and ask this(android.permission.MANAGE_APPOPS) permission but i can't get access to this permission. Is there any other solution for to check restricted_settings?

Comment: Android 13 not implemented these restrictions. Still is possible activate AcessibilityService for sideload apps normally.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version with possible `SecurityException` awareness

```
fun hasAccessRestrictedPerm(context: Context): Boolean {
    // e.g. can enable Accessibility Service with Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 33) {
        true
    } else {
        try {
            val packageManager = context.packageManager as PackageManager
            val applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.packageName, 0)
            val appOpsManager = context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
            val mode = appOpsManager.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(
                "android:access_restricted_settings",
                applicationInfo.uid,
                applicationInfo.packageName,
            )
            mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            false
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            false
        }
    }
}
```